# On the opening of new page have a transition effect run

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am designing a website, and for the navigation, it has a transition it goes through, when its hovered over. On hover, it just expands, all of its been done with CSS. I was wondering if there was a way to have the transition effect still occur when you go to a new page, so when you use the navigation and go to a different page on the website, it would be expanded at the start, then transition back to its off hover state.

Heres the HTML
`

## Photos And Videos

```
        <nav>
            <div id="logo"> 
                <img  src="Images/Logo.png" >
            </div>                  

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="Index.HTML">
                        <i class="fa fa-HOME fa-2x"></i>  <!--this is using the font awesome icons, reffered to in the head. Multiple divs are used as the websote declared it should be done. Purely used for the icons -->
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            HOME
                        </span>
                    </a>                      
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="standards_&_info.HTML">
                        <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            STANDARDS & INFORMATION
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="interesting_info.HTML">
                        <i class="fa fa-magic fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            INTERESTING INFORMATION
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="JOBS.HTML">
                        <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            JOBS
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="photo_&_video.HTML">
                        <i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            PHOTOS & VIDEOS
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="center">
                <h3>Photos</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <img src="Images/placeholder.gif" class="media"alt="Berty">
                    <div class="discription"> 
                        <p>Albert </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap">
                    <img src="Images/placeholder.gif" class="media"alt="Berty">
                    <div class="discription"> 
                        <p>Albert </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap">
                    <img src="Images/placeholder.gif" class="media"alt="Berty">
                    <div class="discription"> 
                        <p>Albert </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap">
                    <img src="Images/placeholder.gif" class="media"alt="Berty">
                    <div class="discription"> 
                        <p>Albert </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr> 

            <div class="center">
                <h3>Videos</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <iframe class="media" 
                        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u81CTfbc99c">
                    </iframe>
                    <div class="discription"> 
                        <p>Green Grass</p> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap">
                    <iframe class="media" 
                        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u81CTfbc99c">
                    </iframe>
                    <div class="discription"> 
                        <p>Green Grass</p> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap">
                    <iframe class="media" 
                        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u81CTfbc99c">
                    </iframe>
                    <div class="discription"> 
                        <p>Green Grass</p> 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap">
                    <iframe class="media" 
                        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u81CTfbc99c">
                    </iframe>
                    <div class="discription"> 
                        <p>Green Grass</p> 
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>  


        </div>
        <footer> 
            rueregrewghe
        </footer>`
```

Here's the CSS

```
    html, body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background: rgb(110, 110, 110);
padding:0;
margin:0;
min-width:1280px;
}
.fa-2x{
    font-size:2em;
}
.container{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.fa {
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
width: 60px;
height: 36px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size:20px;
}
header{
position:fixed;
margin-left:60px;
   width:calc(100% - 60px);
   min-width:1400px;
   height:108px; 
   background:rgb(57, 57, 57);
   z-index:90;
}
footer{
position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:50px; 
   background:rgb(57, 57, 57);
    min-width:1079px;
}
nav {
background:rgb(255, 90, 9);
position:fixed;
top:0;
height:calc(100% - 50px);
min-height:600px;
left:0;
width:60px;
overflow:hidden;
transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
transition:all .1s linear;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
-moz-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-moz-transition:all .1s linear;
-ms-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
float:left;
z-index:100;
}

nav:hover{
width:200px;
transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
transition:all .1s linear;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
-moz-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-moz-transition:all .1s linear;
-ms-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);;
}
nav li {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:250px;
}
nav li>a {
position:relative;
display:table;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
color:#efefef;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration:none;
transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
transition:all .1s linear;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
-moz-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-moz-transition:all .1s linear;
-ms-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-ms-transition:all .1s linear;
transition:all .1s linear;
margin-top: calc(100% / 4);
}
nav .nav-icon {
position:relative;
display: table-cell;
width:60px;
height:36px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size:18px;
}
.nav-text {
position:relative;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width:190px;
font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
}
nav ul,nav li {
outline:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.content{
float:right;
margin-top:108px;
top:0;
height:calc(100% - 178px);
position:relative;
width:89%;
min-width:1140px;
margin-left:200px;
padding-top:10px;
}

#one-box{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    min-width:700px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    background-color:rgb(179, 107, 0);
    height:100%;
    min-height:600px





}
.two-box{
    float:left;


    width:calc(( 80% / 2 ) - 10% );

    height:100%;
    min-width:395px;
    margin-left: 10.5%;


}

.three-box{
    float:left;


    width:calc(( 85% / 3 ) - 6% );

    height:100%;
    min-width:240px;
    margin-left: 6%;

}

.title{
    background-color:rgb(179, 107, 0);
    height:70px;
    margin-bottom:8%;
    margin-top:6%;
    width:100%:
}

.center{
    margin-left:42%;
    width:260px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:rgb(179, 107, 0);
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

.centered{
    margin-left:43%;
    width:260px;
    height:70px;
    background-color:rgb(179, 107, 0);
}

.row{
    display: inline-block;
    height:260px;
    width: calc( 100% - 64px );
    min-width:1300px;
    margin-left:64px;

}

.s_row{
    display: inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width: calc( 100% - 64px );
    min-width:1300px;
    margin-left:64px;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.b_row{
    display: inline-block;
    height:300px;
    width: calc( 100% - 64px );
    min-width:1300px;
    margin-left:64px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.media{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    border:0px;
}



.wrap{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: calc((100% - 1200px ) / 4);


}
.discription{
    width:300px;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:20px;
    background-color:rgb(179, 107, 0)
}

.info{

    background-color:rgb(179, 107, 0);
    height:75%;
    padding-top:10px;
    width:92%;
        padding-left:4%;
    padding-right:4%;
        overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;

}

.infos{

    background-color:rgb(179, 107, 0);
    height:75%;
    padding-top:10px;
    width:92%;
        padding-left:4%;
    padding-right:4%;

    min-height:530px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;

}

#experiment{
    background-color:rgb(179, 107, 0);
    height:100%;
    width:65%;
}
hr{
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    opacity: 0.0001;
}

.small_box{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:rgb(179, 107, 0);
    float:left;
    margin-right: calc((100% - 1200px ) / 4);

}

.box{
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:rgb(179, 107, 0);
    float:left;
    margin-right: calc((100% - 1200px ) / 4);
    border-radius:0px 0px 30px 30px;
}
    .standard{
        width:100%;
        min-width:100%;
        margin-bottom:100px;


        border-spacing:0px;

        padding:10px;
    }
    .standard th {

        border-bottom:solid #000000;
        padding:20px;
        background:rgb(179, 107, 0);
        height:100px;

    }
    .standard td  {
        border-bottom:dashed #000000;
        padding: 0px 10px;

        height:170px;
        min-height:170px;
        width:calc(100% / 3);
        min-width:500px;

    }



    .mid {
        border:1px;
        border-right:solid #000000;
        border-left:solid #000000;


    }

    .involves{
        height:135px;
                background-color:rgb(179, 107, 0);
        width:100%;
        margin-top:0%;

    }
    .small{
        height:30px;
        background-color:rgb(179, 107, 0);
        width:100%;
        margin-top:0%;
        margin-bottom:14.5px;
    }

    .small_ind{
        margin-top:0%;
        height:30px;
        margin-bottom:105px ;
        background-color:rgb(179, 107, 0);
        width:100%;
    }

p{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
    color:white;
    font-size:18px;
}

.read_more{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
    color:#FF6666;
    font-size:18px;
    opacity:0.8;
}
h1{
    font-family: 'Impact', sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:50px;
    color:white;
}
h2{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
    font-size:50px;
    color:white;

}

h2{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
    font-size:50px;
    color:white;

}

h3{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
    color:white;
    font-size:30px;
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1ztL2kq4/

Sorry, I am unsure of how to add an additional page to the JSFiddle, if that is even possible. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like jQuery you can try with this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      var timeout;
    $(someel).hover(
        function() {
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                // do stuff on hover
            }, 2000);
        },
        function(){
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            // do stuff when hover off
        }
      );
    });
```

But you just need to add check if its not home page. Hope this will help you :)

Comment: I tried using the JQuery, but as I hadn't used it before, it proved a bit troublesome. I read through a few tutorials, and made this, '    $(function(){
     $("nav").mouseenter(function(){
      .css({"width": "200px", "overflow": "visible"});
     });
     
     $("nav").mouseleave(function(){
      .css({"width": "200px", "overflow": "hidden"});
     });
    });' but it failed to work. Could you tell me what I did wrong?